# Javascript if else statement OR condition error

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want users can upload only **.mp3** files... My javascript code is below:

```
var type = file.type;
if (type != 'audio/mp3' || type != 'audio/mpeg') {
  alert('Please choose only .mp3 files!');
  return false;
}
```

When I select .mp3 files it gives me **Please choose only .mp3 files!** error.

Comment: i think you want an `AND` instead.

Comment: `var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

This is because you used `!=` , which literally means is not.

So you asked if it is NOT mp3 OR it is not MPEG. So if you select .mp3 it is not an mpeg and will therefore throw the error.

```
var type = file.type;
if (type != 'audio/mp3' && type != 'audio/mpeg') {
  alert('Please choose only .mp3 files!');
  return false;
}
```

I added &&, and now it says  IS NOT mp3 AND IS NOT mpeg.

Comment: It's my answer... I will mark as my answer

Answer (score 2):

Your current condition says that if the file is not an mp3 **or** not an mpeg file, then an error message should be thrown.
What you need is that the file is not an mp3 **and** not an mpeg file.

Comment: I want only give error on antoher types but not mp3. It gives error on all files

Answer (score 0):

you have an **or** operator, so one of them will always be true, and therefore you get the message. use an **and** operator instead.